# Java - convert CET string to Date

Tags: java, datetime

I'm trying to convert this String to Date:

Tue Mar 01 11:46:32 CET 2016

this is the code I have:

```
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy");
Date mTimeStamp = format.parse(getTimeStamp());
```

it throws a ParseExeption...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your format is fine - your issue may be that your default locale is not English and the day and/or month names are not valid in your default language.

This should work as expected:

```
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
Date mTimeStamp = format.parse("Tue Mar 01 11:46:32 CET 2016");
```